# postgresql use subquery as value to insert a json

Tags: json, postgresql, subquery

I would like to optimize a batch insert in posgres. 
To do this, I have to find the latest value of a json data and to use it in another json data. 
For now, my Query looks like this :

```
INSERT INTO audits ("audited_changes") 
 VALUES
  ('update', '{"step_id":[(SELECT ((audited_changes -> `step_id`)::json->>1) FROM audits WHERE auditable_id = 123 order by id desc limit 1)::int,3]}')
```

But postgres don't let me execute the subquery in the json. 
How can I do ?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46360127/edit) your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way i found to make it work was to use the jsonjson_build_object() and json_build_array() functions

My query now looks like :

```
 INSERT INTO audits ("action", "audited_changes", "auditable_id", "auditable_type", "created_at", "version", "request_uuid") 
 VALUES ('update', json_build_object('zone',json_build_array((SELECT ((audited_changes -> 'zone')::json->>1) FROM audits WHERE auditable_id = 1209103 order by id desc limit 1),'qwertyuiop')), 1209103, 'Followup', '2017-11-09 17:03:40 +0400', (SELECT max(version) FROM audits where auditable_id= 1209103)+1, 'cbd34343-1dc1-42b0-ade3-788dfb2c1172')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you trying:

```
INSERT INTO audits ("audited_changes") 
 SELECT 'update'
 , '{"step_id":['||((audited_changes -> 'step_id')::json->>1)::int||',3]}' 
 FROM audits 
 WHERE auditable_id = 123 
 order by id desc 
 limit 1
```